# XQuery with string-join, one parameter is string and other is number

Tags: xquery

I want to list respective Year with Total Number of Orders.

```
<Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Year>2010</Year>
    <Order>20,000</Order>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <Year>2011</Year>
    <Order>20,000</Order>
    <Order>35,000</Order>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <Year>2012</Year>
    <Order>20,000</Order>
    <Order>23,000</Order>
    <Order>40,000</Order>
  </Sample>
</Samples>
```

I am expecting output as -

```
Year        Orders
2010        1
2011        2
2012        3
```

As the number of `<Order>` elements will itself tell me the total number of Orders, I tried with the following in BaseX -

```
for $x in doc("Sample")/Samples/Sample
   return <li>{string-join ( ($x/Year, count($x/Order)) , " # ")}</li>
```

But I'm getting an error and its obvious because I am using integer instead of string in the `string-join` function. Or is there any other way to get the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string-join` expects strings, not a number which `count` returns. Add a cast and it will run.

```
for $x in /Samples/Sample
   return <li>{ string-join( ($x/Year, xs:string(count($x/Order))), " # ") }</li>
```

I fixed two more errors:

- Why are you querying Attribute `Y` on year? There is none.
- You will want to count `<Order>` tags, not `<Orders>`.

Maybe using `concat` could make the code more readable (as long as you're only using two parameters)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. and I have corrected the errors. Thanks a lot again :)